# Why do area calculations of OSM polygon shapefiles return negative values in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, area

Whenever I tried to calculate the area of polygon shapefiles (OSM, Geofabrik) part of the polygons have negative values. All values appear to be right except the fact that around half of them are negative (f.e. -5734 m² instead of 5734 m²).

Before I calculated the area I reprojected the shapefiles from WGS84 to UTM33.

Comment: You may need to validate the polygon geometry (reversed rings would report negative area)

Comment: Wrong ring ordering. Repair geometry and try again